# Configuring multiple subdomains to serve static content in django using cloud front

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I have a website developed using django and hosted on AWS EC2.
I am using amazon cloud front as my content delivery network with origin server as amazon S3. I have created multiple cnames and added it to the cloud front distribution. 
Using just one cname and using it as Cloudfront domain works as expected.

Now I want to extend it so that content can be downloaded in parallel. But AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN setting takes a particular url which can be assigned to only one cname at a time.

How to assign multiple cnames for static contents. Or is there some other way to achieve the same?

Following is the relevant content from my django settings.py file

```html
INSTALLED_APPS += ('s3_folder_storage',)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage'
DEFAULT_S3_PATH = "media"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 's3_folder_storage.s3.StaticStorage'
STATIC_S3_PATH = "static"

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "mybucket"
CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = "*******.cloudfront.net"
CLOUDFRONT_CNAME = "data1.example.com"

MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % DEFAULT_S3_PATH
MEDIA_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, DEFAULT_S3_PATH)
STATIC_S3_PATH = "static"
STATIC_ROOT = "/%s/" % STATIC_S3_PATH
STATIC_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, STATIC_S3_PATH)
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = CLOUDFRONT_CNAME #important: no "http://"
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True #default, but must set to false if using an alias on cloudfront

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '******'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*****'
```

Comment: You would need to do this at the template level, the same way that you would load different files from different CDNs. You can always make your own setting to pass to the template, like `CLOUFDFRONT1`, `CLOUDFRONT2`, etc, and use those prefixes in your static urls: `<link href="{{ CLOUDFRONT1 }}/foo.js" />`

Comment: Hi Brandon,
But that will mean hard-coding the url instead of using the static template tag which is the recommended way

Comment: How so? Your `CLOUDFRONT1` could be: `[domain]/path/path/` to which you are just adding the file path, which is no different than using the `static` template tag.

Comment: Check this link which says why we should not use STATIC_URL in templates
http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/stop-using-static-url-in-templates/

Comment: Yes, I understand that, however, the static application only allows you to use one domain.

Comment: Yes, that was my concern, eventually I will also end up doing the same. But posted this question to check if there is some better way which I might have missed

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Unless you're loading a ton of files that aren't cacheable, using several domains might not actually help you out very much. You might consider leveraging django-compressor which works with S3, which is great for CSS files, and something like require.js to load JS files asynchronously.

Comment: css and js are not the ones which I am concerned about.
I have to load a lot of images which is the reason I am planning use multiple distributions. I will surely try using compressor though.
Thanks for the info

Comment: How far forward can you set your expires headers?

Comment: one week should be fine, but that won't help in my case because there are literally millions of images and based on the combination of user input, some 20 full size and 40 thumbnails will be fetched. Its highly unlikely that I will be able to utilize browser cache. To give you an idea of the website, it is similar to shoesofprey.com for a different product and offering much more customizations